add native android module to flutter plugin for debugging
I have a native android Ml-kit module. I am trying to add it to flutter plugin (android) as a module dependency
settings.gladle:
include ':ml-kit'
project(':ml-kit').projectDir=new File(rootDir, "<path to ml-kit>")

build.gradle:
implementation project(":ml-kit")

Is it possible to add native android module to flutter plugin?
what am I missing?
